# LWJGL per face lighting

Tags: java, opengl, lighting

I tried making something that works out normals from faces, I dont know if it works and i get smooth shading on my model.

It seems to work fine as a quad, but when i tried a cube, it only rendered 1 quad at the top which gets randomly smooth shaded, and everything else is black. If i turn off lighting, it only renders 1 quad which is at the top.

Model class:

```
public class Model {
private int vbo, ibo, vao, tbo, nbo;
private int count = 0;

private float[] normal;

private Matrix4f modelMatrix;
private Vector3f position, rotation;

private Texture texture;
private boolean hasTexture = false;

private String matrixName;

public Model(float[] vertices, String matrixName, int[] ... indices) {
    if (!initialized) {
        log.err("JORL not initialized", "Run 'init()' at the start of your program");
        System.exit(1);
    }

    this.matrixName = matrixName;

    vao = glGenVertexArrays();
    vbo = glGenBuffers();
    ibo = glGenBuffers();
    nbo = glGenBuffers();

    for (int[] face : indices)
        count += face.length;

    glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, ibo);
    for (int[] face : indices)
        glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, put(face), GL_STATIC_DRAW);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);

    glBindVertexArray(vao);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, put(vertices), GL_STATIC_DRAW);
    glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, false, 0, 0);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
    glBindVertexArray(0);

    normal = new float[count];
    int current = 0;
    for (int[] face : indices) {
        Vector3f p1 = new Vector3f(vertices[face[0] * 3], vertices[face[0] * 3 + 1], vertices[face[0] * 3 + 2]);
        Vector3f p2 = new Vector3f(vertices[face[1] * 3], vertices[face[1] * 3 + 1], vertices[face[1] * 3 + 2]);
        Vector3f p3 = new Vector3f(vertices[face[2] * 3], vertices[face[2] * 3 + 1], vertices[face[2] * 3 + 2]);

        log.info(p1.toString());
        log.info(p2.toString());
        log.info(p3.toString());

        Vector3f U = p2;
        Vector3f V = p3;
        U.sub(p1);
        V.sub(p1);

        normal[current * 3] = (U.y * V.z) - (U.z * V.y);
        normal[current * 3 + 1] = (U.z * V.x) - (U.x * V.z);
        normal[current * 3 + 2] = (U.x * V.y) - (U.y * V.x);

        System.out.println(normal[current * 3]);
        System.out.println(normal[current * 3 + 1]);
        System.out.println(normal[current * 3 + 2]);


        current++;
    }

    glBindVertexArray(vao);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, nbo);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, put(normal), GL_STATIC_DRAW);
    glVertexAttribPointer(2, 3, GL_FLOAT, false, 0, 0);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
    glBindVertexArray(0);

    modelMatrix = new Matrix4f();
    position = new Vector3f(0, 0, 0);
    rotation = new Vector3f(0, 0, 0);
}

public void setTexture(ShaderProgram shader, Texture texture, float[] coords) {
    this.texture = texture;
    hasTexture = true;
    shader.bind();
    shader.editUniform(1, "has_texture");
    shader.editUniform(texture.getSampler(), "tex");
    shader.bind();

    tbo = glGenBuffers();
    glBindVertexArray(vao);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, tbo);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, put(coords), GL_STATIC_DRAW);
    glVertexAttribPointer(1, 2, GL_FLOAT, false, 0, 0);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
    glBindVertexArray(0);
}

private FloatBuffer put(float[] data) {
    FloatBuffer pData = BufferUtils.createFloatBuffer(data.length);
    pData.put(data).flip();
    return pData;
}

private IntBuffer put(int[] data) {
    IntBuffer pData = BufferUtils.createIntBuffer(data.length);
    pData.put(data).flip();
    return pData;
}

public void increaseX(float increase) { position.x += increase; }
public void increaseY(float increase) { position.y += increase; }
public void increaseZ(float increase) { position.z += increase; }

public void increaseRotX(float increase) { rotation.x += increase; }
public void increaseRotY(float increase) { rotation.y += increase; }
public void increaseRotZ(float increase) { rotation.z += increase; }

public void render(ShaderProgram shader) {
    modelMatrix.identity();

    modelMatrix.translate(position);
    modelMatrix.rotateX((float) Math.toRadians(rotation.x));
    modelMatrix.rotateY((float) Math.toRadians(rotation.y));
    modelMatrix.rotateZ((float) Math.toRadians(rotation.z));

    shader.editUniform(modelMatrix, matrixName);

    glBindVertexArray(vao);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, ibo);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(2);
    if (hasTexture) {
        glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);
        texture.bind();
    }

    glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, count, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, 0);

    glDisableVertexAttribArray(2);
    glDisableVertexAttribArray(0);
    if (hasTexture) {
        glDisableVertexAttribArray(1);
        texture.unbind();
    }
    glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
    glBindVertexArray(0);
}

public void delete() {
    glDeleteBuffers(vbo);
    glDeleteBuffers(ibo);
    glDeleteBuffers(nbo);
    if (hasTexture) {
        glDeleteBuffers(tbo);
        texture.delete();
    }
    glDeleteVertexArrays(vao);
}
```

}

I have a light class which just outputs a colour and position vector to the shader.
The camera is working fine and everything else works fine if i dont use lighting. (apart from more than 1 face).

geometry shader:

```
    #version 400

layout(triangles) in;
layout(triangle_strip, max_vertices = 3) out;

in vec4 colour[];
in vec2 pass_tex_coords[];

in vec3 pass_normal[];
out vec3 t_normal;
out vec3 t_light;

out vec2 pass_tex_coords_;
out vec4 pass_colour;

uniform mat4 projection;
uniform mat4 view;
uniform mat4 model;

uniform vec3 light_position;

void main(void) {
    for (int i = 0; i < gl_in.length(); i++) {
        vec4 world_pos = projection * view * model * gl_in[i].gl_Position;
        gl_Position = world_pos;

        pass_tex_coords_ = pass_tex_coords[i];
        pass_colour = colour[i];

        t_normal = (view * model * vec4(pass_normal[i], 0)).xyz;
        t_light = (view * vec4(light_position, 1)).xyz;

        EmitVertex();
    }

    EndPrimitive();
}
```

fragment shader:

```
#version 400

in vec4 pass_colour;
in vec2 pass_tex_coords_;

in vec3 t_normal;
in vec3 t_light;

out vec4 out_colour;

uniform int has_texture;
uniform sampler2D tex;

uniform vec4 light_colour;

void main(void) {
    vec3 n_normal = normalize(t_normal);
    vec3 n_light = normalize(t_light);
    float cosTheta = dot(n_normal, n_light);

    if (has_texture != 1) {
        out_colour = texture(tex, pass_tex_coords_) * pass_colour * cosTheta;
    } else {
        out_colour = pass_colour;
    }
}
```

If anybody has any links to per face lighting that would be great, I couldnt find any.
I do think this has something to do with my messy Model class with the indices parameter.

EDIT
All faces render now, now how do i fix the weird smooth gradient lighting to be a per face flat lighting?

Answer (score 0):

Uploading the index buffer seems to be wrong:

```
for (int[] face : indices)
    glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, put(face), GL_STATIC_DRAW);
```

This code overrides in each iteration the bound element array buffer, but it seems as if you would want to add the indices one after the other to the buffer. What you actually want has to be something like this:

```
//Calculate total length of indices
int lenght = 0;
for (int[] face : indices)
    length += face.length;

//Pack data together
IntBuffer pData = BufferUtils.createIntBuffer(length);

int start_idx = 0;
for (int[] face : indices)
{
    pData.put(face, start_idx, face.length);
    start_idx += face.length;
}

pData.flip();

//Upload to OpenGL
glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, pData, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
```

Note, that each entry into indices (`int[] face`) has to have exactly three elements, since OpenGL Core Profile can only draw triangles. You could thus replace the first loop by `int length = indices.length * 3;`

Comment: Ok thanks, it renders the whole cube now. But what about the lighting? It renders as a smooth gradient, but its just a massive mess. It seems only 2 faces are affected by the light and the faces affected just do some crazy thing